# Why does my data in a linked list change/corrupt within nested functions?

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I am writing code for a discrete time CPU schedule simulator. It simply generates processes and schedules them accordingly. I am currently implementing the FCFS schedule. I understand the nature of a discrete time simulator, but I am have trouble implementing in C++.

The problem occurs in the jump between `handleNextEvent()` and `generateProcessDeparture()`. At some point the data in my linked-list event queue gets corrupted. (Line 267 in `eventQueue.cpp`)

The idea is that `handleNextEvent()` pulls the next event from the event queue, an arrival (type 1), and thus generates a departure (type 2) for the same process (PID 1). Everything is good up to this point.

Once control is release by `generateProcessDeparture()` and returns to `handleNextEvent()`, the original arrival event is deleted, which **SHOULD** leave only the departure event.

Instead I've got gobbly gook - plus a extra copy of the arrival event somehow.  I've researched scope and pointers, but I am a novice to C++, and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Any insight appreciated. Thank you.

**eventQueue.cpp**

```cpp
/*
    EVENT TYPES
        -1  HEAD: There can be only one head in the linked list of events.
        0 NEW: If 0 the event is new and blank.  For error checking.
        1 arrival:  Indicates arrival of a single process.
        2 departure:  Indicates completion of process.  If the event exists within
            the event queue, then the simulator has NOT YET accounted for it in 
            system state or metric report.
*/

#include "eventQueue.h"
#include <iostream>

eventQueue::eventQueue(int dac, int aar, float ast, float q){

    // Initiatialize head of event linked list.
    eHeadPtr = new event;
    eHeadPtr->type = -1;
    eHeadPtr->time = -1;
    eHeadPtr->next = NULL;

    rqHeadPtr = new event;
    rqHeadPtr->type = -1;
    rqHeadPtr->time = -1;
    rqHeadPtr->next = NULL;

    defaultArrivalCount = dac;
    averageArrivalRate = aar;
    averageServiceTime = ast;
    averageServiceRate = 1 / ast;
    quantum = q;
}

void eventQueue::runFCFS(){
    std::cout << "\n\nrunFCFS()...";

/*  generateProcessArrival();
    generateProcessArrival();
    generateProcessArrival();
    generateProcessArrival();
    generateProcessArrival();
    generateProcessDeparture(*eHeadPtr->next);*/

    while(handledProcessCount < defaultArrivalCount){
        std::cout << "\n\nCurrent event queue: ";
        printEventQueue();
        std::cout << "\nCurrent ready queue: ";
        printReadyQueue();
        std::cout << "\nLatestArrivalTime: " << latestArrivalTime;
        std::cout << "\nNextDepartureTime: " << nextDepartureTime;


        if(eventQueueEmpty()){
            generateProcessArrival();
        }

        handleNextEvent();
        //std::cout << "\n\nEvent queue after handleNextEvent:";
        //printEventQueue();

        while(latestArrivalTime <= nextDepartureTime){
            std::cout << "\nLatestArrivalTime( " << latestArrivalTime << " ) <= nextDepartureTime( " << nextDepartureTime << " )";
            generateProcessArrival();
        }
    }
}

bool eventQueue::eventQueueEmpty(){
    if (eHeadPtr->next == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool eventQueue::readyQueueEmpty(){
    if (rqHeadPtr->next == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void eventQueue::printEvent(event e){
    std::cout << "\n  [ TYPE: " << e.type << ", TIME: " << e.time << ", PID: "
        << e.proc.id << ", BURST: " << e.proc.cpuBurst << ", A_TIME: " << 
        e.proc.arrTime << ", S_TIME: "  << e.proc.servTime << ", R_TIME: " << 
        e.proc.remTime << ", NEXT: " << e.next << " ] ";
    return;
}

void eventQueue::printEventQueue(){

    if (eventQueueEmpty()){
        std::cout << "\n  [ ]";
    }
    else{
        event* tmpPtr = eHeadPtr;

        do{
            tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            printEvent(*tmpPtr);
        }while(tmpPtr->next != NULL);

        tmpPtr = NULL;
        return;
    }
}

void eventQueue::printReadyQueue(){

    if (readyQueueEmpty()){
        std::cout << "\n  [ ]";
    }
    else{
        event* tmpPtr = eHeadPtr;

        do{
            tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            printEvent(*tmpPtr);
        }while(tmpPtr->next != NULL);

        tmpPtr = NULL;
        return;
    }
}

double eventQueue::generateBurst(){

    int intRand = rand() % 100;
    float realRand = intRand / 100.0;
    double burst = ((-log(1 - realRand))/averageServiceRate);
    return burst;
}

double eventQueue::generateArrivalDiff(){

    double diffTime;
    int intRand = rand() % 100; 
    double realRand = intRand / 100.0;
    double dTime = ((-log(1 - realRand)/averageArrivalRate));
    return dTime;
}

void eventQueue::generateProcessArrival(){
    std::cout << "\n\ngenerateProcessArrival()...";

    // Establish pointers.
    event* frontPtr = new event;
    event* backPtr = new event;
    event* newPtr = new event;

    double burst = generateBurst();
    double arrivalDiff = generateArrivalDiff();
    latestArrivalTime += arrivalDiff;
    newProcessID++;

    newPtr->type = 1;
    newPtr->time = latestArrivalTime;
    newPtr->proc.id = newProcessID;
    newPtr->proc.arrTime = latestArrivalTime;
    newPtr->proc.cpuBurst = burst;
    newPtr->proc.servTime = 0;
    newPtr->proc.remTime = burst;

    std::cout << "\nCreated new arrival event:";
    printEvent(*newPtr);

    if(eventQueueEmpty()){
        eHeadPtr->next = newPtr;
        std::cout << "\nEvent queue was empty.  Added new arrival event to queue:";
        printEventQueue();
    }
    else{
        backPtr = eHeadPtr;
        frontPtr = eHeadPtr->next;

        while((newPtr->time > frontPtr->time) && (frontPtr->next != NULL)){
            backPtr = frontPtr;
            frontPtr = frontPtr->next;
        }

        if ((frontPtr->next == NULL)&&(newPtr->time > frontPtr->time)){
            frontPtr->next = newPtr;
            std::cout << "\nAdded new arrival to end of event queue:";
            printEventQueue();      
        }
        else{
            backPtr->next = newPtr;
            newPtr->next = frontPtr;
            std::cout << "\nAdded new arrival to (center/front) of event queue.";
            printEventQueue();  
        }
    }
    frontPtr = NULL;
    backPtr = NULL;
    newPtr = NULL;
    return;
}

void eventQueue::generateProcessDeparture(event arr){
    std::cout << "\n\ngenerateProcessDeparture()...";

    // Establish pointers.
    event* frontPtr = new event;
    event* backPtr = new event;
    event* newPtr = new event;

    // Generate departure based on arrival event.
    event dep;
    dep.type = 2;
    dep.proc = arr.proc;
    dep.time = arr.proc.arrTime + arr.proc.cpuBurst;
    newPtr = &dep;

    std::cout << "\nCreated new departure event:";
    printEvent(*newPtr);

    if(eventQueueEmpty()){
        eHeadPtr->next = newPtr;
        std::cout << "\nEvent queue was empty.  Added new arrival event to queue:";
        printEventQueue();
    }
    else{
        backPtr = eHeadPtr;
        frontPtr = eHeadPtr->next;

        while((newPtr->time > frontPtr->time) && (frontPtr->next != NULL)){
            backPtr = frontPtr;
            frontPtr = frontPtr->next;
        }

        if ((frontPtr->next == NULL)&&(newPtr->time > frontPtr->time)){
            frontPtr->next = newPtr;
            std::cout << "\nAdded new arrival to end of event queue:";
            printEventQueue();      
        }
        else{
            backPtr->next = newPtr;
            newPtr->next = frontPtr;
            std::cout << "\nAdded new arrival to (center/front) of event queue.";
            printEventQueue();  
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\ngenerateProcessDeparture final check:";
    printEventQueue();  
    frontPtr = NULL;
    backPtr = NULL;
    newPtr = NULL;

    return;
}

void eventQueue::handleNextEvent(){
    std::cout << "\n\nhandleNextEvent()...";

    // Establish pointers.
    event* frontPtr = new event;
    event* backPtr = new event; 
    frontPtr = eHeadPtr->next;
    backPtr = eHeadPtr;
    systemClock = frontPtr->time;

    if (frontPtr->type == 1){
        std::cout << "\nArrival event next.";
        printEventQueue();
        //printEvent(*frontPtr);

        if (readyQueueEmpty() && cpuIdle){
            std::cout << "\nReady queue empty and cpu idle.";
            generateProcessDeparture(*frontPtr);

            printEventQueue();      
            backPtr->next = frontPtr->next;     // Remove event from event queue.
            std::cout << "\n\nreturn to handleNextEvent()...";
            cpuIdle = false;
            std::cout << "\ncpuIdle: " << cpuIdle;
            std::cout << "\nCurrent event queue:";
            printEventQueue();          
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "\nReady queue not empty and/or cpu not idle.";
            pushReadyQueue(*frontPtr);
            backPtr->next = frontPtr->next;
        }
    }
    else if (frontPtr->type == 2){
        std::cout << "\nDeparture event next.";
        printEvent(*frontPtr);

        if (!readyQueueEmpty()){
            std::cout << "\nReady not empty.  Loading next event to CPU.";
            event* tmpPtr = rqHeadPtr->next;    //Set tmpPtr to first item in readyQueue.
            generateProcessDeparture(*tmpPtr);  //Creature departure event.
            rqHeadPtr->next = tmpPtr->next;     //Delete old event.
            tmpPtr = NULL;                      
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "\nReady queue empty and cpu idle.";
            cpuIdle = true;
            backPtr->next = frontPtr->next;
        }
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "\nERROR: bad event type in event queue.";
    }

    handledProcessCount++;
    frontPtr = NULL;
    backPtr = NULL; 
    return;
}

void eventQueue::pushReadyQueue(event e){

    // Establish pointers.
    event* frontPtr = new event;
    event* backPtr = new event; 

    while((e.time > frontPtr->time) && (frontPtr->next != NULL)){
        backPtr = frontPtr;
        frontPtr = frontPtr->next;
    }

    if ((frontPtr->next == NULL) && (e.time > frontPtr->time)){
        frontPtr->next = &e;
        std::cout << "\n\nAdded new arrival to end of ready queue:";
        printReadyQueue();      
    }
    else{
        backPtr->next = &e;
        e.next = frontPtr;
        std::cout << "\n\nAdded new arrival to (center/front) of ready queue.";
        printReadyQueue();  
    }

    frontPtr = NULL;
    backPtr = NULL; 
    return; 
}
```

**eventQueue.h**

```cpp
/*
    EVENT TYPES
        -1  INVALID: if 0 the event is new and blank.  For error checking.
        0 head: There can be only one head in the linked list of events.
        1 arrival:  Indicates arrival of a single process.
        2 departure:  Indicates completion of process.  If the event exists within
            the event queue, then the simulator has NOT YET accounted for it in 
            system state or metric report.
*/

#ifndef EVENTQUEUE_H
#define EVENTQUEUE_H
# include <cstddef>
# include <tgmath.h>
# include <ctime>

struct process{
    int id = -1;
    double arrTime = -1;
    double cpuBurst = -1;
    double servTime = -1;
    double remTime = -1;
};

struct event{
    int type = -1;
    double time = -1;
    process proc;
    event* next = NULL;
};

class eventQueue{
    private:
        event* eHeadPtr;
        event* rqHeadPtr;
        int defaultArrivalCount;
        int handledProcessCount = 0;
        int newProcessID = 0;
        int averageArrivalRate;  // lambda
        float averageServiceTime;   // Ts
        float averageServiceRate;   // mu
        float quantum;  //q
        double latestArrivalTime = 0;
        double nextDepartureTime = 0;
        bool cpuIdle = true;
        double systemClock = 0;

    public:
        eventQueue(const int, int, float, float);
        void runFCFS();
        bool eventQueueEmpty();
        bool readyQueueEmpty();
        void printEvent(event);
        void printEventQueue();
        void printReadyQueue();
        void generateProcessArrival();
        double generateBurst();
        double generateArrivalDiff();
        void generateProcessDeparture(event);
        void handleNextEvent();
        void pushReadyQueue(event);
};

#endif // EVENTQUEUE_H
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
/*
    EVENT TYPES
        0  INVALID: if -1 the event is new and blank.  For error checking.
        1 head: There can be only one head in the linked list of events.
        2 arrival:  Indicates arrival of a single process.
        3 departure:  Indicates completion of process.  If the event exists within
            the event queue, then the simulator has NOT YET accounted for it in 
            system state or metric report.
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include "eventQueue.h"

void testInput(int, char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    char divider[] = "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    const int DEF_ARR_COUNT= 10;

    std::cout << "\n" << divider;
    std::cout << "\nWelcome to the Simulator";

    //TEST CMD LINE INPUT
    testInput(argc, *argv);

    // Setup environment and first default events (arrivals).
    //int lambda = std::stoi(argv[2]);
    //float Ts = std::stof(argv[3]);
    //eventQueue eq(TOTAL_PR, lambda, Ts);
    //eq.initDefaultArr();

    //eq.printQueue(15);

    eventQueue eq(DEF_ARR_COUNT, std::stoi(argv[2]), std::stof(argv[3]), std::stof(argv[4]));
    eq.runFCFS();
    //eq.printWithoutCount();



    std::cout << "\n" << divider;
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}

void testInput(int argc, char* argv){
    if ((argc < 5) || ((argv[1] > 4) && (argv[1] < 1))){
        std::cout << "\n\nERROR: invalid commandline input";
        std::cout << "\n\tCommand line: <scheduler> <lambda> <Ts> <quantum>";
        std::cout << "\n\tScheduler: [1,FCFS], [2, SRTF], [3, HRRN], [4, RR]";
        std::cout << "\n\tExample: ./main 2 15 0.06 0.01";
    }
}
```

Here is some example output that I am getting:

```
anne@laptop:~/Dropbox/College/Current/Opsy/ROUND_4$ g++ main.cpp eventQueue.cpp -o main
anne@laptop:~/Dropbox/College/Current/Opsy/ROUND_4$ ./main 1 10 0.05 0.01

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to the Simulator

runFCFS()...

Current event queue: 
  [ ]
Current ready queue: 
  [ ]
LatestArrivalTime: 0
NextDepartureTime: 0

generateProcessArrival()...
Created new arrival event:
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 
Event queue was empty.  Added new arrival event to queue:
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 

handleNextEvent()...
Arrival event next.
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 
Ready queue empty and cpu idle.

generateProcessDeparture()...
Created new departure event:
  [ TYPE: 2, TIME: 0.359373, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 
Added new arrival to end of event queue:
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0x7fff5cc50520 ] 
  [ TYPE: 2, TIME: 0.359373, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 
generateProcessDeparture final check:
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0x7fff5cc50520 ] 
  [ TYPE: 2, TIME: 0.359373, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0 ] 
  [ TYPE: 1, TIME: 0.350656, PID: 1, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 0.350656, S_TIME: 0, R_TIME: 0.00871767, NEXT: 0x7fff5cc50520 ] 
  [ TYPE: 1556416656, TIME: 4.6627e-310, PID: 1556415824, BURST: 0.00871767, A_TIME: 4.6627e-310, S_TIME: 6.95322e-310, R_TIME: 6.95322e-310, NEXT: 0x55d52b320ec1 ] 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From what I understand of segmentation faults, its often due to referencing an array or list out of bounds?

Comment: I see a few `new` statements but no `delete` statement. That means at least a few memory leaks.

Comment: Can you use std::unique_ptr?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I thought that by putting my pointers to NULL near the end of each function would "clean" things up, but I will look into delete.  Thank you.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I will research that as a solution as well.  Thank you.

Comment: That would be true if you used smart pointers, or if C++ had a garbage collector, but here you're using raw pointers, which are dumb by nature and can only point to something and cannot manage the lifetime of whatever they point to. In general, manual memory management in C++ is really hazardous, and you should prefer smart pointers whenever possible rather than using `new` and `delete` directly.

Comment: `event* frontPtr = new event;` dynamically allocated a new `event` and assigned the address of it to `frontPtr`. `frontPtr` is the only thing you have that can find this allocation. Following it with `frontPtr = eHeadPtr->next;` is a bad idea because now nothing points to the allocation. It is leaked. You do not have to create a new allocation every time you define a pointer. Pointers can point to preexisting data. What you really want here is `event* frontPtr = eHeadPtr->next;` Only use `new` when you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 2):

Question code in this line:

```
newPtr = &dep;
```

You should change it to

```
*newPtr = dep;
```

Because `dep` is defined on the stack buffer, after execute function `generateProcessDeparture`, the stack buffer will be overwritten.

Comment: Even better, ditch `dep` and assign directly to the `event` allocated for `newPtr` earlier.